# set value attribute for cross origin iframe form input using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, swift, iframe, cross-domain

I'm using JavaScript code in IOS swift. I can execute the Javascript and jquery code for the action trigger in rendered web-view.

I can set values in other all pages like user information, shipping details pages but on the payment card details page all input tags render from the cross-origin iframe.

I'm trying to set the value attribute of that input tag in payment page  ( This document comes from cross-origin iFrame ) but it gives me the below error.

```
ERROR: VM27055:5 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “https://www.demo.com” from accessing a cross-origin frame.

**This is my Javascript code:**

var ifrm = document.getElementsByClassName(‘wpwl-wrapper-cardNumber gl-input’)[0].firstChild;
console.log(ifrm);
setTimeout(function() {
var win = ifrm.contentWindow;
console.log(win);
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
console.log(doc);
var input = doc.getElementsByTagName(‘input’)[0];
console.log(input);
input.setAttribute(‘value’,‘4242424242424242’);
}, 2000);
```

**Help me to resolve this error.**

Comment: you can't directly access cross origin iframes with javascript - look at using `window.postmessage` as long as you have access to write the code for the content in the iframe - if you do not "control" the content in the iframe, then you can't access it, period - this is a security measure to stop sites from embedding bank sites and stealling all your monies

Comment: I wonder how tools like LastPass or 1Password are able to inject credentials into an iframe such as the one Disney uses for their login page. https://disneyland.disney.go.com/login